# Expanding table row: auto-expand detail row if result set = 1?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table in angular 1.35 where if the user clicks an icon at the left of the row, it shows a "detail" row beneath the row.  This part works perfectly:

```
  <tbody ng-repeat-start="p in tracking.packages | filter:tracking.search">
      <!-- <tr  ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails" ng-click="$event.originalEvent.dropdown" class="expander"> -->
      <tr class="expander">
        <td>
          <div class="row-arrow" ng-class="{'down-arrow' : showDetails}" ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails"></div>
        </td>
        <td>{{p.receivedDate | date: "MM/dd/yyyy &ndash; h:mma"}}</td>
        <td>{{p.carrier}}</td>
        <td>{{p.trackingNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{p.status}}</td>
        <td><span ng-if="p.status !== 'Attempted'"><span ng-if="tracking.currentStatus !== 'undelivered'">{{p.deliveredTo}}</span></span></td>
        <td>{{p.addressedTo}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row-details expanded" ng-show="showDetails" ng-class="{ 'active': showDetails }">
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="7">
ETC....
```

Now I have a new requirement that if we  land of this page from a search and get a result set (from a search field) of only one row, then I need to expand the row.

Since the row shows and hides via the state of the `showDetails` variable, I tried adding ng-init to the icon:

```
<div class="row-arrow" ng-class="{'down-arrow' : showDetails}" ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails" ng-init="{showDetails : shown==1}"> </div>
```

But obviously I have it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [filter alias in ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) from Angular 1.3 (beta 17) and above.

> `variable in expression as alias_expression` – You can also provide an optional alias expression which will then store the intermediate results of the repeater after the filters have been applied. Typically this is used to render a special message when a filter is active on the repeater, but the filtered result set is empty.
>
> For example: `item in items | filter:x as results` will store the fragment of the repeated items as results, but only after the items have been processed through the filter.

in your case, you can alias the repeater, and if the alias has a count of exactly 1 item, then you can toggle your expansion variable.

```
<tbody ng-repeat-start="p in tracking.packages | filter:tracking.search as searchResults">
    ....
    <div class="row-arrow" ng-class="{'down-arrow' : showDetails}" 
         ng-click="showDetails = !showDetails" 
         ng-init="showDetails = (searchResults.length == 1)"> </div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, posting from phone; I will update shortly.

Comment: Obviously I prefer the repeater for the very reason of scopes, since toggling any one is self-contained. Is there a way to preserve that but add an additional condition to the ng-show that depends on the resultset length?

Comment: after reviewing the code a bit and doing a bit of research, I have a better understanding of what you are attempting to do, and I have a working solution; I'll update the answer momentarily.

Comment: That makes sense, but Angular is having an issue with the init expression: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '=' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 14 of the expression [{showDetails = (searchResults.length == 1)}] starting at [= (searchResults.length == 1)}].`

Comment: Angular drives me crazy sometimes.  You code works without the curly braces: `ng-init="showDetails = (searchResults.length == 1)"`

Comment: @Steve sorry about that; I fixed the code for future readers.  I should have realized I didn't need the braces, but you're right, sometimes angular syntax is a bit of a challenge.